# How can I make this better

Tags: java, android

Ok here I have a switch case statement which is falling through and trying every option.  Basically I want something that if the user enters the letter A in the textbox the background will change to b! if they dont enter the letter A then I want it to stop executing the code.   But what has been happening is if the user enters lets say for example the letter Q when the background is letter A then the background will change to letter R instead of telling the user that they are wrong.  basically I would like to know how I can stop the background from changing if the user does not enter the letter they are on here is the code.

```
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                char ch = words.getText().toString().charAt(0);

                switch(ch - 'A') {

                case 0: 
                    //A;

                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersb);

                    break;
                case 1:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersc);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersd);

                    break;
                case 3:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.letterse);

                    break;
                case 4:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersf);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersg);
                break;
                case 6:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersh);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersi);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersj);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersk);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersl);
                    break;
                case 11:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersm);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersn);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.letterso);
                    break;
                case 14:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersp);
                    break;
                case 15:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersq);
                    break;
                case 16:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersr);
                    break;
                case 17:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.letterss);
                    break;
                case 19:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.letterst);
                    break;
                case 20:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersu);
                    break;
                case 21:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersv);
                    break;
                case 22:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersw);
                    break;
                case 23:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersx);
                    break;
                case 24:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersy);
                break;
                case 25:
                    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lettersz);
                    break;
```

would it be better if I set the pictures in an array and then went from there? Ive tried including If switch case, but it didnt work at all....

Comment: I think using an array would be a good idea. you would likely end up solving your problem by first simplifying it

Comment: yeah thats what i thought, I just started programming not to long ago so im not that good with arrays lol...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd pre-populae an array and invoke:

```
gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(myArray[ch - 'A']);
```

It will make your code **much** more readable.

You can also do it with a `Map<Character,MyImage>` - it might allow you to add more features easily in the future.

If you do that, invokation will be using

```
gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(myMap.get(ch));
```

Note that the array/map needs to be populated only once in the application's runtime.

Comment: Map? you have a tutorial link for that?

Comment: @RichTalcik it is an interface for mapping keys to values. Look at the docs for [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and the class [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) which will probably be relevant for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, put all the `R.drawable.abc` inside an Array and then address its index.

```
int[] bgImg = {R.drawable.a, ... , R.drawable.z}
char ch = words.getText().toString().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

int index = ch - 'A';
if(index > 0 && index < bgImg.length){
    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(bgImg[index]);
} else {
    gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.standardImage);
}
```

Also note, that I'm using `toUpperCase()` to make sure you can substract the capital `'A'`

Comment: Ima try this and see how if it works I will let you know thanks

Comment: when you say the else part { what exactly do you mean by standardImage? Like a default one that I want to load when the index finishes? or a default one that loads when the person gets it wrong?

Comment: No, that would be the image, that gets loaded once the user inputs somthing else than A-Z, a number for example.

Comment: ok using the array works and makes things easier but how would I stop the array from going to the one after if for instance the user is on array 0 (Letter A) and the user accidentally draws array 2 (Letter C), how would I stop the background from changing to letter D and instead tell the user they are wrong and keep the background letter A (or array one)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      char ch = words.getText().toString().charAt(0);
      int id = getResources().getIdentifier("letters" + ch, "drawable",  context.getPackageName())
      gestureViewer.setBackgroundResource(id);
 }
```

}